# How to define an interface that VueJS dynamic components must implement?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I am making a form dialog which is meant to be generic with regard to the kind of form it embeds. For this purpose, I use VueJS dynamic components to define which kind of form a particular dialog should instantiate.

It "works", but it is not type-safe: any component can be passed to the dialog. I would rather constraint them to implement a particular interface (let's say, a component should emit a `created` event to be considered a Form component).

Here's what I tried :

```js
// FormComponent.vue
// This is my attempt at defining an "abstract" component
// that defines the interface other form components should implement

<script setup lang="ts" generic="ItemType extends { id: string }">
defineEmits<{
  (event: 'created', item: ItemType): void
  (event: 'edited', item: ItemType): void
}>()
</script>
```

```js
// FormDialog.vue

<template>
  <v-dialog persistent v-model="dialog">
    <v-card title="Form">
      <v-card-text>
        <component :is="form" />
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-dialog>
</template>

// Using generics to define the interface of the form passed as prop

<script
  setup
  lang="ts"
  generic="
    ItemType extends { id: string },
    Form extends ComponentExposed<typeof FormComponent<ItemType>>
  "
>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { ComponentExposed } from 'vue-component-type-helpers'
import FormComponent from './FormComponent.vue'

const dialog = ref(false)

defineProps<{ form: Form }>()

</script>
```

This does not work, I can still pass any component as prop to `FormDialog` with no complaints whatsoever from the compiler.